# Non-positive-definite forecast error covariance matrix encountered at period 1 ARIMA update

Tags: python, arima

I am trying to update an ARIMA model after training it. However, this error keeps popping up Non-positive-definite forecast error covariance matrix encountered at period 1. Why is it so?

Here's my code if you want to reproduce it:

```
#general
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
%matplotlib inline
import yfinance as yf
from pmdarima.arima import ADFTest

ticker = "0118.KL"
data = yf.Ticker(ticker)
df = data.history(period="max",end="2020-04-30")

df = df.filter(items=['Close'])

n=365
train = df[:-n]
test = df[-n:]

from pmdarima import auto_arima

model = auto_arima(train,trace=True,m=7,error_action='ignore', suppress_warnings=True)
model.fit(train)

plt.plot(train, label='Train')
plt.plot(test, label='Valid')
plt.plot(forecast, label='Prediction')
plt.show()
forecast = model.predict(n_periods=n)
forecast = pd.DataFrame(forecast,index = test.index,columns=['Prediction'])

model.update(test)
```

Why does this happen? Any insight would be much appreciated.

EDIT: The result of the trained model on test data is displayed in the graph below.

[image: Result]

The predicted data is the green line and test data the orange line.

Comment: Could you show us the results of model? The parameters it fit? In particular the covariance matrix.

Comment: @AnonymousEmu I've updated to show the results of the trained model in the form of a graph. I'm not too sure what you mean by the parameters and the covariance matrix.

Comment: As per http://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/1.6.1/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.ARIMA.html#pmdarima.arima.ARIMA does your model have any arima_res attributes?if not that, then can you show us what errors you are suppressing in your auto ARIMA